# Installing tensorboard built from source

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

This is about a tensorboard which is built from source, not about pip-installed one.

I could successfully build it.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard.git
$ cd tensorboard/
$ bazel build //tensorboard
tensorflow/tensorboard$ bazel build //tensorboard
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
......................................
         : (log messages here)
Target //tensorboard:tensorboard up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/tensorboard/tensorboard
INFO: Elapsed time: 326.553s, Critical Path: 187.92s
INFO: 619 processes: 456 linux-sandbox, 12 local, 151 worker.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1268 total actions
```

Then yes I can run it as documented in [tensorboard/README.md](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard), and it works.

```
$ ./bazel-bin/tensorboard/tensorboard --logdir path/to/logs
```

The problem is, I'd like to run it as if installed via pip like this:

```
$ tensorboard --logdir path/to/logs
```

But as far as I looked for, no script provided to create `.whl` file so that we can locally-pip-install it, unlike [tensorflow provides one like this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#build_the_pip_package).

```
$ bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
$ sudo pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.8.0-py2-none-any.whl
```

So... can anybody show how to do that? Making packaging script would solve this, but it should exist somewhere as long as tensorboard is provided via pip anyway. :)

My workaround so far is not clean enough:

```
$ ln -s /my/build/folder/tensorboard/bazel-bin/tensorboard/tensorboard ~/bin
$ ln -s /my/build/folder/tensorboard/bazel-bin/tensorboard/tensorboard.runfiles ~/bin
```

I appreciate your suggestions, thanks!

Update July-21:

Thanks to W JC, I found instruction is already there in tensorboard/pip_package/BUILD.

```
# rm -rf /tmp/tensorboard
# bazel run //tensorboard/pip_package:build_pip_package
# pip install -U /tmp/tensorboard/*py2*.pip
```

Though unfortunately it shows error in my environment, and I guess it's local issue maybe because I'm using anaconda.

But basically the problem was resolved. It should basically work as long as running on supported environment.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there exists an script in the /tensorboard/pip_packages try to build wheels

Comment: Thanks, I could run and build successfully as follows:

<code>
    (cd to tensorflow/tensorboard)
    bazel build -c opt //tensorboard/pip_package:build_pip_package
</code>

Though I couldn't find wheel...

Comment: try to this command bazel run //tensorboard/pip_package:build_pip_package

Answer (score 1):

`bazel run //tensorboard/pip_package:build_pip_package ./` did generate the **wheel** out, but in the folder where `bazel-bin` points to. In my case, it's generated at `~/.cache/bazel/_bazel_peijia/b64ba42719633ff75eec6880decefcd3/execroot/org_tensorflow_tensorboard/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/tensorboard/pip_package/build_pip_package.runfiles/org_tensorflow_tensorboard/tensorboard-2.10.0a0-py3-none-any.whl`

Comment: Hi NexeraP. Yes, it would be drastically changed with the current version. Please follow what you have found. My question was about the 2018 version of TensorFlow.